# Feature "as column" in my mysql where statement

Tags: mysql, where-clause, mysql-error-1054

I have a mysql query that subtracts amounts from several rows to show a new amount in a new column called "Balance".  I would like it to only show those records where Balance > '0'. See below:

```
    SELECT 
visits.visit_id,
visits.payment_increments,
((visits.total - visits.paid) - SUM(payments.amount)) AS Balance,
schedule.schedule_date
FROM
visits
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
schedule ON visits.schedule_id = schedule.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
payments ON visits.visit_id = payments.visit_id
WHERE
Balance>'0'
GROUP BY visits.visit_id
```

Is there a way to use my new column in the WHERE statement? Right now, all it shows is an error -> Error Code:1054 Unknown column 'Balance' in 'where clause'.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

```
GROUP BY ... HAVING Balance >0
```

**Note :** `HAVING` works works with non-table columns ..Since **Balance** is not a column of main table, so this is an imaginary column, so it will work with `HAVING` just like `WHERE` works with table columns

[`Read more...`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/)

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you. Sorry about the temporary brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT 
visits.visit_id,
visits.payment_increments,
((visits.total - visits.paid) - SUM(payments.amount)) AS Balance,
schedule.schedule_date
FROM
visits
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
schedule ON visits.schedule_id = schedule.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
payments ON visits.visit_id = payments.visit_id

GROUP BY visits.visit_id HAVING  Balance>'0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same SQL query just you have to mention full column name

```
   SELECT 
   visits.visit_id,
   visits.payment_increments,
   ((visits.total - visits.paid) - SUM(payments.amount)) AS Balance,
   schedule.schedule_date
  FROM
     visits
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
   schedule ON visits.schedule_id = schedule.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
  payments ON visits.visit_id = payments.visit_id
WHERE
  ((visits.total - visits.paid) - SUM(payments.amount))>'0'
 GROUP BY visits.visit_id
```